# Is it possible to make isometric game of 200 * 200 tiles per map in Unity?

Tags: unity, isometric

We made an isometric game in AndEngine. Now we want to convert this game into Unity. I am searching for tiles map support/plugin in Unity. I come across a plugin called Map and nav http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/138355-Tile-Based-Map-amp-Nav . but the problem is it only support 50*50 tiles per map. My map is 200 * 200 tiles. I want to know is there any plugin or way to acheive 200 * 200 tiles per map in Unity ?

Thanks

Comment: The way is to make your own renderer. Which technology to use questions are not a good fit for the Q/A format of the site. Check the [FAQ] for more info.

Comment: Your link doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I get a page about a glass tutorial.

Comment: I am sorry. I changed the link.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you're talking about mobile, and a 3D game. If either of these is untrue, you should be perfectly fine in any situation.

I'm currently working on a 3D tile-based mobile game. I've written my own tile engine for Unity (note: I didn't write my own renderer, I honestly don't see the point). In the game the camera rotation is fixed and it's ortographic, which allows some optimizations.

While having a 200x200 map is easily possible (and has been done) with my system, older phones like my Samsung Galaxy S are simply too slow to use it, even after optimizations. Fps can be between 5 and 20 which means it's not enjoyable.

One important thing I noticed is that after optimizing graphics a lot (custom static batching, throwing away invisible sides, generating a custom terrain mesh, etc.) the choke point wasn't really graphics. Since with isometric games you have a pretty good idea of what the player sees at each point, it's very easy to minimize the amount of data that needs to be loaded.

So right now the weakest link is the amount of units and non-static stuff on the map.
Pathfinding is acceptable with a pre-calculated graph (using A* from Aaron Granberg). For collisions I use an optimized model with boxes spanning multiple tiles (pre-calculated) and unity's physics engine, but I don't do any dynamic body stuff, only checking for collisions in certain situations (player movement mostly).

So the final answer is: yes. You may have to cut back on the features, but it is definitely possible.

Answer (score 3):

It is possible to make an isometric game with 200 * 200 tiles per map in Unity3D, but you will have to make your own renderer and make several optimizations to your code, probably more than you would have anticipated.

As for your renderer, you will want to have complete control over your mesh data so you can do things like hide faces that are not visible to the camera, removing vertices that are to far away, combine meshes, and more.

For code optimizations, the way you index your tiles could arguably be the most important factor, as that is 200 * 200 potential objects. You should build a queue for loading the tile objects or their data.

Comment: Can you elaborate with a little more than "make your own renderer" for the benefit of the asker and future readers? It's not like you can just toss Unity's renderer out the window. You have to change how you use it.

Comment: Sure thing. What I added should help explain.

Comment: i have to remember to just put the top comment in a answer for rep